# Some more explanation of Hibernate's merge

Tags: hibernate

I need some clarification on Hibernate merge method. How does it exactly work. When i have an entity that is detached, and I want it to get reatached, does Hibernate look only un current session for same entity, or in all Hibernate sessions?

Is there any way to use merge on transistent entity?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate's merge is to be used when you might have more than one instance of an object in the current memory at one time, and you want Hibernate to save any and all changes made to any instance of the object. This can happen, for example, when you've loaded the object through two different means during validation.

An issue that can cause confusion is the difference between an application session and a Hibernate session. It's possible to open and close more than one Hibernate session during an application session.

If you load an object instance in the first Hibernate session, then close the session, that instance becomes detached. If you open a new session, then load the same object (same ID), Hibernate will construct a new instance, and if you try to use saveOrUpdate on the object obtained in the first session, Hibernate will throw a NonUniqueObjectException.

So while the current Hibernate session is only concerned with itself, part of its infrastructure is to be aware of what objects exist in the larger application session that are mapped Hibernate entities and thus it should consider in operations like save or merge.

Merge is a way to tell Hibernate "I want you assume any changes I made to this Hibernate entity should be saved, even if I made them to a different instance of the object than the once I'm asking you to save." SaveOrUpdate is a way to tell Hibernate to be more conservative and throw an Exception instead.

There's some more specifics about the differences between Hibernate's saveOrUpdate and merge [in this article](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/) in my blog.

Answer (score 0):

it looks in the current hibernate session only, not all hibernate sessions.

for your second question, you cannot by definition of 'transient' (what i believe you meant, not 'tansistent').  Transient means the entity has not been saved.  Merge means nothing hear.